# How to numpy vectorize a function to be applied to every row of numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gaussian

I have this function I wrote for calculating the probability of x given the parameters of a multivariate Gaussian. Where x is a feature with 2 features and mu is a vector of 2 features and sigma is 2x2.

```
def prob(x, mu, sigma):
    n = len(x)
    var = x - mu
    sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)
    rhs = np.exp(-0.5*np.matmul(np.matmul(var.T, sigma_inv),var))
    lhs = 1/(((2*np.pi)**(n/2))*np.linalg.det(sigma)**.5)
    return rhs*lhs
```

But this only works if x is 1D array. I want to be able to vectorize and optimize this for multi dimensional x (for example x is 100x2) currently I have.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    curr_prob = prob(x[i], mu, sigma)
        
    if i == 0:
        prob = curr_prob
    else:
        prob = np.append(prob, curr_prob)
```

But this is very slow. I heard there's a way to use np.vectorize for this or np.pyfunc, but I'm not sure how to apply those.

Comment: First, use of `np.append` in a loop is slow. `np.array([prob(i, mu, sigma) for i in x])` should be faster.  But the speedup-vectorization requires rewriting `prob` to work directly with the 2d `x`.  Note that `inv, matmul` and `det` can work with 3d arrays, effectively 'batches' of matrices.

Comment: @hpaulj would you mind posting how to apply inv, matmul and det on 3D arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj sorry I meant 2D arrays. Essentially if you can post how to do the batched operations I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
np.apply_along_axis(prob, 1, x, mu, sigma)
```

Comment: Yea I looked into that I believe it passes the axis argument to probs as well which it doesn't take

Comment: `apply_along_axis` does not speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how shapes flow in current function

```
x (2,), mu (2,), sigma (2,2)

def prob(x, mu, sigma):
    n = len(x)             # 2
    var = x - mu           # (2,)-(2,)
    sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)    # (2,2) no change w/ x
    rhs = np.exp(-0.5*np.matmul(np.matmul(var.T, sigma_inv),var))
    # var is (2,), var.T is the same (2,)
    # (2,)@(2,2)=>(2,); (2,)@(2,)=> scalar
    # np.exp(-0.5 * var @ sigma_inv @ var

    lhs = 1/(((2*np.pi)**(n/2))*np.linalg.det(sigma)**.5)
    # np.linalg.def(sigma)**.5 - no dependence on x
    # the whole lhs doesn't vary with x
    # lhs is scalar

    return rhs*lhs    # scalar
```

now consider what changes if `x` is (100,2)

```
def prob(x, mu, sigma):
    n = x.shape[-1]    

    sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)    # (2,2) or (n,n)?
    lhs = 1/(((2*np.pi)**(n/2))*np.linalg.det(sigma)**.5) # scalar

    var = x - mu           # (100,2)-(2,)
    # by broadcasting this is (100,2)-(1,2)=>(100,2) 
    # no change needed

    rhs = var@sigma_inv@var
    # (100,2) @ (2,2) => (100,2)
    # (100,2) @ (100,2)  oops
    # var@sigma_inv@var.T   
    # (100,2) with (2,100)=>(100,100)   no! 
    # np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',var,sigma_inv,var) 
    # 
    rhs = np.exp(-0.5*rhs)    # (100,2)
    return rhs*lhs
```

On my first try `var@sigma_inv@var` worked with (2,), but gave me an error with (n,2).  But the `einsum` expression gets the `i`, batch dimension right.  I could probably correct the double @ to get that right as well.

```
def prob(x, mu, sigma):
    n = x.shape[-1]    
    sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)
    lhs = 1/(((2*np.pi)**(n/2))*np.linalg.det(sigma)**.5)

    var = x - mu
    rhs = np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',var,sigma_inv,var)
    rhs = np.exp(-0.5*rhs)
    return rhs*lhs
```

Testing:

```
In [495]: x = np.array([1,2.]); mu=np.array([.5,.5]);
In [496]: sigma = np.array([[1,.5],[.5,3]])
In [497]: X = np.array([x,x,x+1])
In [498]: prob(X,mu,sigma)
Out[498]: array([0.06375113, 0.06375113, 0.01785457])
```

Your function also produces 0.06375 for `x`.

The `einsum` can be written as:

```
np.squeeze(var[:,None,:]@sigma_inv@var[:,:,None])
```

but that's not any clearer, and probably not much different in speed.